# jQuery passing returning values from click function

Tags: jquery

I've got two functions and I'd like to pass a variable out of one into another. 
First function

```
var redirect_url;

$("li a.nav_item").click(function(){

        redirect_url=$(this).attr("data-url");
        alert(redirect_url); //correctly alerts the value



        });

function update_counter(){

                alert(redirect_url); //alerts Undefined
                $("#final_countdown").text(timer);



    }
```

Comment: Call the `update_counter` in the click handler. You can't return values from handler, and shouldn't have to.

Comment: I would except I'm calling it later in the code via a set interval.

Comment: What would the point of returning a value from the click handler be? Handlers may return true/false signifying if they handled the event or not. If the goal is to compute and store a value then do it completely within the handler.

Comment: @user1352096 then your alert should show the correct value of `redirect_url` after the click handler has been fired. What is your problem?

Comment: I should explain further.  I've got a countdown timer on the page when the user clicks a link (in a set) I need to capture the url of that link and once the countdown is expired they are then redirected to that URL. I should admit I'm a bit of a jQuery noob so I'm floundering here a little.

Comment: so just update the redirect_url var with the new link and you should be good. Put your code in a http://jsfiddle.net , it should bea simple solution

Comment: @user1352096 I see no problems, just return false from the click so it doesn't handle the link... http://jsfiddle.net/Ka6hY/

Comment: Oh man you're right! Newbie mistake.

Answer (score 0):

When your timer fires, it is not in the same context that it was when you defined it. If you would like the function it executes to be in the same scope as when the timer was created, do something like the following:

```
function something() {
    var x = 5;
    var t = setTimeout(function(){
        alert(x);//will alert 5
    }, 500);
}
```

In this scenario, the function that is executed by the timer is scope-aware of the value of x, and can use it even though it fires at a later time.

Here is another example which more closely matches your situation:

```
$("li a.nav_item").click(function(){
    redirect_url=$(this).attr("data-url");
    setTimeout(function(){
        location.href = redirect_url;
    }, 1000);
});
```

On click, the attribute containing the new url is fetched. Then a timer is created, and calls a function in 1000ms. Since it was written this way, the function that is executed in 1000ms is aware of the variable "redirect_url" and can act on it.